# Calling functions multiple times versus using livequery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Many of you probably encountered this situation. For example you have a jQuery fade effect that fires on mouse over a link. At some point you add new links in the document trough ajax, so you need to apply the fade effect to them too.

There are two possibilities:

- you call the fade function again after the ajax completes
- you use something like [livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) in your initial document.ready function to apply the fade on the links

Which method would you choose and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery has a native function that does this without the need of an extra plugin.  see [$.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Edit: furthermore, your first option seems like code smell to me.  keep it DRY and use `$.live()`

Comment: yes, but it only works with click events and stuff like that. You can't run a function after a element is added, only when something happens to that element..

Comment: could you update your original post to give a more clear example then? the one you gave was simple event delegation.

Comment: yes that was a bad example :) ok, here's real-life situation: you have a list of comments on a page, and a `show more` link which fires a ajax that gets more comments. Each comment has stuff like 'rate down', 'rate up', 'reply' etc... Basically jQuery stuff, which needs to be applied to new comments as well. And not on a specific event, but when new comments are added...

Answer (score 3):

`livequery` adds overhead that is simply unnecessary unless you just don't have access to the javascript that is adding the dynamic elements.

If you're talking about event handlers that are triggering the fade, then you could use jQuery's *event delegation* capabilities the [`delegate()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method  *(preferred)* or the [`live()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method .

If you're not talking about event handlers, then I'd definitely go with applying the code yourself in a callback to the AJAX request. `livequery` is slick, but should be an absolute last resort in my opinion.

Comment: That was fast! I was just adding an answer to point out the delegate method as well